# PACT testing: correct way to write PactDslJsonBody

Tags: java, json, testing, junit, pact

I have the following JSON format

```
{
    "file": {
        "version": "v1.4",
        "release": "1.1"
    },
    "status": "ON",
    "document": {
        "status": "NOT_FOUND",
        "release": "undefined"
    }
}
```

and I would like to know how I can add the format into my PactDslJsonBody, something like?

```
DslPart result = new PactDslJsonBody()
        .stringType("file.version", "v1.4")
        .stringType("file.release", "1.1")
        .stringType("status", "ON")
        .stringType("document.status", "NOT_FOUND")
        .stringType("document.release", "release") 
        .asBody();
```

Or is it possible to add a Java Pojo? I have the class ApplicationResponse:

```
public class ApplicationResponse {

  private File file;
  private String status;
  private Document document;

  //...

}

Something like ??
    DslPart result = new PactDslJsonBody()
            .object(ApplicationResponse)
            .asBody();
```

What could be the best approach? could you please add an example

Answer (score 3):

We attempted to do what you are trying to do using reflection to stub out our pojos. However, our classes carry many Lombok annotations & we couldn't get default values out from builder annotated fields. We gave up trying to use it. But a dev with more time could achieve this no doubt.

I am now actively creating Pacts for our projects and use both `LambdaDsl` and `PactDslJsonBody`to build the interaction.

```
DslPart actualPactDsl = LambdaDsl.newJsonBody((body) -> {
            body
                .stringType("status", "ON")
                .object("document", (doc) -> {
                    doc.stringType("status", "NOT_FOUND");
                    doc.stringType("release", "undefined");
                })
                .object("file", (file) -> {
                    file.stringType("version", "v1.4");
                    file.stringType("release", "1.1");
                });
}).build();
```

or

```
String pactDslJson = new PactDslJsonBody()
    .stringType("status", "ON")
    .object("document")
    .stringType("status", "NOT_FOUND")
    .stringType("release", "undefined")
    .closeObject()
    .object("file")
    .stringType("version", "v1.4")
    .stringType("release", "1.1")
    .closeObject()
    .getBody().toString();
```

Both of these examples will produce the Json string from your example.

The [examples](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/tree/master/consumer/junit/src/test/java/au/com/dius/pact/consumer/junit/examples) that are a part of [Pact-Jvm](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm) are really helpful to get your head around the different types of tests you can create.

Comment: examples 404'ed :(

Comment: My bad, updated link